# PHP - (Large website) Multi-purpose functions or single-purpose functions?

Tags: php

Is it desirable to have functions which do multiple things?

For example

`ShowEditContact($form)` serves to display the form for a contact's info AND also handles the updating of contact info

Vs

`ShowContact($contactID)` which does display and `SubmitContact($form)` which handles form processing.

Comment: Why would `ShowContact` do anything other than show?

Comment: This is not a very specific question and is likely to be closed. HOwever I would say that your best approach is probably to use objects, with specific methods on the object for each piece of functionality.  Taking a one function fits all approach in programming is generally a really bad approach.

Comment: I think you should reword your question to actually get to the bottom of what you are asking as at the moment the question reads very cryptically

Comment: `"Is it desirable ... to have functions which do multiple things"` - No.  Each function should do one thing and do it well.  More specifically, each function should have only one reason to change.  See the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function names should reflect what they do. If a function is named `ShowContact`, it should show a contact. It shouldn't delete/update a contact any more than it should brew a cup of coffee.

Comment: In this specific example, the function was named "ShowEditContact" to provide some clarity that it did more than just showing.

Comment: Variable names should reflect their use just like function names. If you're looking to *show* a contact, it's still unlikely you'll be sending a `$form` to the function even if you've named it `ShowEditContact`.

Comment: Well, in the "single function" perspective, $form could be an array, but it could also be a "contactID" so if the variable were named more appropriately it would be called "$form_or_contactID"

Comment: @Cryptic If I saw that in a code base I'd yell at people. Variables shouldn't require a magic decoder ring like that. Split the functions up into discreet, functional units - `editContact` and `showContact` - and be done with it.

Comment: editContact vs submitContact ? I don't suppose you have a great argument for the former over the latter?

Comment: That's just an example. It can be `saveContact` or `processContact` or something along those lines.